# SQL import and export wizard - getting black boxes

Tags: sql, import, fixed-width

I am attempting to import a fixed width file into Sql using the import and export wizard. Below is a short bit of background about the data.

```
First field (state) is char (2)
Second field is char (2)
Third field is char (6)
```

There are 22 of them but the issue starts at the beginning and carries through til the end. In the import wizard, I specify the input column width as 2 and the output column width as 2. It seems simple enough.

However, starting with row 2 I get two black boxes in place of the state value. It there pushes the state value into the second column and starts a domino effect.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What is the file type? It sounds like a carriage return and line feed that your not accounting for as line terminators.

Comment: .data1. I open it up with notepad and each row is a continuous string that ends (cr)(lf)

Comment: The solution was that I inserted a column at the end titled blank and made it char (2) to account for the two black boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I inserted a column at the end titled blank and made it char (2) to account for the two black boxes. –